What are the best ways to solve large scale multi commodity flow problems?
I am interested in large scale instances. 1000 Commodities and a graph with 10000 nodes.
The commodities have a start node, but no destination node. Each node can only be visited by one commodity. Each arc has a positive cost value and the goal is to maximize flow.
I am interested in open source tools.
It can for example modelled via the vehicle routing api of OR tools.
Is this the best approach?

Is the graph dense/sparse? I’m not sure it matters, but it might.

Google OR-Tools or Networkx from Pypi.org
